# Remove specific characters from column names in r

Tags: r

Have data set with several hundreds of columns, the column names look like this "drop.loc1.genom1.tret1.gwas2.a", I need to remove everything except loc1 and tret1 -- so it will look like this "loc1.trt1" ---- any hint or help will be highly appreciated 
thanks

Comment: Do you really want to drop the e in tret?  can anything follow loc and tret other than numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is to use `strsplit`:

```
sapply(strsplit(strings, "\\."), function(x)
    paste0(x[c(2, 4)], collapse = "."))
[1] "loc1.tret1"     "loc2.tret2"     "loc100.tret100"
```

---

### Sample data

(From ManuelBickel's answer)

```
strings = c("drop.loc1.genom1.tret1.gwas2.a",
            "drop.loc2.genom1.tret2.gwas2.a",
            "drop.loc100.genom1.tret100.gwas2.a")
```

Comment: Amazing way of tackling this. Although all the functions you are using are vectorized. So no need of `sapply` eg you could do `do.call(paste,c(sep=".",do.call(rbind.data.frame,strsplit(strings, "\\."))[c(2,4)]))` i guess.. But still you have my +1

Comment: @hema You're very welcome; I've changed my solution slightly to make it more succinct (and used the fact that `strsplit` is vectorised in `x` as Onyambu pointed out).

Answer (score 2):

You might try something like..

UPDATE: Have updated the code with benchmark of all version proposed so far.
In case @Onyambu posts an answer you should accept that one, since the approach is the fastest.

```
strings = c("drop.loc1.genom1.tret1.gwas2.a",
            "drop.loc2.genom1.tret2.gwas2.a",
            "drop.loc100.genom1.tret100.gwas2.a")
gsub("(^.*\\.)(loc\\d+)(\\..*\\.)(tret\\d+)(\\..*$)", "\\2.\\4", strings, perl = T)
[1] "loc1.tret1"     "loc2.tret2"     "loc100.tret100"

f1 = function(strings) {
  unname(sapply(strings, function(x)
    paste0(unlist(strsplit(x, "\\."))[c(2, 4)], collapse = ".")))
}

f2 = function(strings) {
  gsub("(^.*\\.)(loc\\d+)(\\..*\\.)(tret\\d+)(\\..*$)", "\\2.\\4", strings, perl = T)
}

f2b = function(strings) {
  sub(".*(loc\\d+).*(tret\\d+).*","\\1.\\2",strings)
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  f1(strings),
  f2(strings),
  f2b(strings)
)

# Unit: microseconds
#         expr    min      lq      mean median      uq      max neval
# f1(strings)  58.818 64.1475 136.31964 68.687 76.1880 5691.106   100
# f2(strings)  78.161 79.9380 106.08183 83.293 88.6215 2110.333   100
# f2b(strings) 27.238 29.6070  53.29592 32.765 35.1330 1872.299   100
```

Comment: Nice way of tackling this. Although you can shorten it as `sub(".*(loc\\d+).*(tret\\d+).*","\\1.\\2",strings)`. still got my +1

Comment: Thank you for the hint and the improvements, you are absolutely right. You should post a separate answer to get the credits.

Answer (score 1):

You could used `dplyr::rename_all()` or `dplyr::select_all()` and `gsub()` using Onyambu's regex pattern from the comment to Manuel Bickel's answer:

```
library(dplyr)

# sample data
df <- data_frame(drop.loc1.genom1.tret1.gwas2.a = 1:2,
                 drop.loc23.genom2.tret2.gwas2.a = 3:4,
                 drop.loc3.genom3.tret34.gwas3.a = 5:6)

# both rename_all and select_all give the same results:
df %>% 
  rename_all(~gsub(".*(loc\\d+).*(tret\\d+).*","\\1.\\2", .))

df %>% 
  select_all(~gsub(".*(loc\\d+).*(tret\\d+).*","\\1.\\2", .))

# A tibble: 2 x 3
  loc1.tret1 loc23.tret2 loc3.tret34
       <int>       <int>       <int>
1          1           3           5
2          2           4           6
```